# Pull GET parameter from URL in functions.php

Tags: php, functions

I've followed the documentation from [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var), but my `functions.php` file still is not getting the `token` (`abcd`) variable from the URL: `https://example.com/reset-password/?token=abcd`

My functions.php file includes the following:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = "token";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

...

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_password_reset_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
function custom_password_reset_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    // Make POST request to change password
            $token = get_query_var( 'token', "fk" );
            write_log("TKN: {$token}");
    }

    return $result;
}
```

For some reason, `get__query_var` always returns `fk` instead of `abcd`.

Comment: If wpcf7_validate_text is handled in a separate AJAX request, then the token parameter is not going to exist.

Comment: But then how can I get the `GET` parameter in my `Contact Form 7` validation?

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 provides a recipe for [**Validation as a Filter**](https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/) which looks very much like what you are trying to do.

Adapting their example to your code, I believe the following should work for you:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_password_reset_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
function custom_password_reset_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {        
    if ('token'==$tag->name){
        $token = isset($_POST['token']) ? $_POST['token'] : "fk";
        write_log("TKN: {$token}");
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
$token = $_REQUEST['token']
```